# PL/SQL trouble at create trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY(
INVENTORY_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
ITEM_NAME VARCHAR2(255),
QUANTITY NUMBER,
PRICE NUMBER,
ITEM_SIZE VARCHAR(255),
INVENTORY_VALUE NUMBER);
```

===

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY_AUDIT(
DATE_CHANGED DATE,
USER_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
INV_ID NUMBER(6),
OLD_QUANTITY NUMBER,
NEW_QUANTITY NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT fk_INV_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (INV_ID)
    REFERENCES INVENTORY (INVENTORY_ID));
```

===

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INV_CHG
    BEFORE UPDATE OF QUANTITY
    ON INVENTORY
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.QUANTITY <> :OLD.QUANTITY THEN
        INSERT INTO INVENTORY_AUDIT 
        VALUES (GETDATE(), v('APP_USER'), :NEW.INVENTORY_ID, :OLD.QUANTITY, :NEW.QUANTITY)
    END IF;
END;
```

===

```
    ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057


3.     ON INVENTORY
4.     FOR EACH ROW
5. BEGIN
6.     IF :NEW.QUANTITY <> :OLD.QUANTITY THEN
7.         INSERT INTO INVENTORY_AUDIT
```

===

I tried to create trigger that triggered by inventory table's quantity change.
But it throws an error and syntax looks fine for me.
I tried without IF whole statement but still had same problem.
That means my create trigger statement has problem right?
But I cannot find it.

Comment: please execute "show errors" and show the error message.

Comment: @OldProgrammer show errors doesn't work for me. I am working on Oracle apex. just type 'show errors' on empty command line or under the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- missing semi-colon at the end of the `INSERT` statement
- use `sysdate` instead of `getdate`

Here's how:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INV_CHG
  2      BEFORE UPDATE OF QUANTITY
  3      ON INVENTORY
  4      FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6      IF :NEW.QUANTITY <> :OLD.QUANTITY THEN
  7          INSERT INTO INVENTORY_AUDIT
  8          VALUES (sysdate,          --> sysdate instead of getdate()
  9                  v('APP_USER'),
 10                  :NEW.INVENTORY_ID,
 11                  :OLD.QUANTITY,
 12                  :NEW.QUANTITY
 13                 );                 --> missing semi-colon here
 14      END IF;
 15  END;
 16  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```